# Seamless Single Sign-On not working in .NET 4.5.2 WebBrowser from Windows 10

Tags: .net, windows-10, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

This is a bit of a inconsistent question since I don't know a lot about Azure Active Directory and Single Sign-on, but here goes.

I have a .NET 4.5.2 WinForms application, which performs a Single Sign-On on Azure through the .NET WebBrowser control.
This application works on Windows 7 and Windows 8, but not on Windows 10.
The browser performs most of the Single Sign-On dance but stops at "Trying to sign you in" and after ~5 seconds ends up showing the input box for the email address.
On the computer tested, the Single Sign-On works correctly through a browser such as Internet Explorer, Edge and Chrome.

I've tried creating another .NET application, duplicating the code from the failing application and *that works*.
Any other application I have created works as it should, just not the one I am deploying.

I believe it's a "hybrid" Active Directory setup, which leads me to believe there could be *something* in the setup, which is blocking the application (I did try renaming the executable, but that didn't work either), it all just seems so strange to me and I haven't been able to find any information proving this.

- If the Azure account is added to Windows 10, the Single Sign-On works in the application, but unfortunately, this is not an acceptable solution.
- Browser emulation is set to Internet Explorer 10 `10000 (0x2710)`.
- I'm told that there is no group policies in place and nothing "unusual" about the environment.

Any ideas/suggestions would be most helpful.

I will update this question with any information required when asked, but since I don't exactly know what I'm talking about, I want to keep it as basic as possible.

It should also be mentioned that I'm not in control of the failing machine, so any testing will be quite difficult, but I will do my best.

**Update**

This problem seems to be related to the fact the host process is running in 64-bit, which for some reason doesn't work. Changing the host process to 32-bit makes the SSO flow work as expected, but just not in 64-bit. Really strange :/

**Update #2**

I've asked a new question because I've since come closer to the problem: [Azure AD Password Hash Sync, Seamless SSO and 64-bit WebBrowser .NET control not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56629287/azure-ad-password-hash-sync-seamless-sso-and-64-bit-webbrowser-net-control-not)

Comment: Which browser? Chrome requires a whitelisted domain.

What form of authentication are they using? Pass-through? ADFS?

It may be worth opening a technical support ticket with Azure for this so that someone can look into the environment.

Comment: It's the WebBrowser component which hosts an instance of Internet Explorer. I believe it's Internet Explorer 11 (Windows 10) but running in IE10 compatibility mode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure AD Password Hash Sync, Seamless SSO and 64-bit WebBrowser .NET control not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56629287/azure-ad-password-hash-sync-seamless-sso-and-64-bit-webbrowser-net-control-not)